# Junit5 never hitting @BeforeAll inside @Suite class

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit4, junit5

Currently going through the process of upgrading from Junit4 to Junit5 and running into a bit of a hurdle with something that used to work in Junit4.

Wondering if there is a way to access the @BeforeAll/@AfterAll (formerly @BeforeClass/@AfterClass) within a class which is also a @Suite

Example:

```
@Suite
@SelectClasses({
        SquareService.class,
        TriangleService.class
})
public class ShapeTestSuite { 

    @BeforeAll
    public void beforeAll() {
        Log.info("Shape Test Suite Start!");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public void afterAll() {
        Log.info("Shape Test Suite End!");
    }

}
```

I've tried adding an extension to this class/suite, but that also does not seem to work.  What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@BeforeAll and @AfterAll runs before any execution of @Test, @TestFactory, etc.
So if you create one them you will see that your code will be run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` are annotations from Jupiter, which is one (of many) JUnit 5 engines. `@Suite`, however, is independent and can run tests and test suites combined from any JUnit 5 engine. That’s why you cannot use a before-all method in a suite class.

Comment: Is there a way to get the suite structure and still be able to have @BeforeAll to work?

Comment: Not that I know of. You may consider to use different mechanisms of JUnit5 like tags and/or disable/enable annotations and/or extensions to reach your goal.